# BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s!

Tags: 14.04, lenovo

EDIT: I've changed the title from 'Ubuntu Freeze // Lenovo T440' to what I believe is the actual bug. Hopefully this will generate more answers.

EDIT 2: Bizarrely, this freeze only occurs when the laptop is using a Wifi network. When using an ethernet connection, as I have done for around 12 hours done, the freeze did not occur once.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo T440. It has been running okay for months, until a few days ago the computer started randomly freezing. It doesn't appear to be dependent on what program is running -- it has happened during word processing and regular internet browsing.

Once the computer freezes, the usual reset method of Alt+PrtSc+REISUB doesn't work.

How can I diagnose the problem, and does anyone have an idea of what it might be?

EDIT: Upon doing a hard reset, Ubuntu prompted me to report a problem. I'm not sure if this report *is* the problem leading to the computer freezing, or whether it is a result of the hard reset. Regardless, here it is:

Package: linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic 3.16.0-38.52-14.04.1
ProblemType: KernelOops
Title: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 23s! [swapper/2:0]
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted

Comment: is it possible to reboot your machine during freeze via Magic SysRq Keys? http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Magic_SysRq_key ALT+print+(r/e/i/s/u/b)

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, no it is not unfortunately.

Comment: What wireless chip, what driver, what errors do you get from dmeag output or in syslog?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? My T440s is randomly freezing and I can't for the life of me figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue...like today. So I thought it was my 5500 series video graphics. Nope. Drivers? Nope. A dual-boot problem? Idk. I tried to update my kernel but it wouldn't show up on the GRUB menu.

Try this:

Install a newer kernel (I installed 4.1 rc3)(http://sourcedigit.com/16629-install-linux-kernel-4-2-rc3-on-ubuntu-15-04-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-14-10/)

Follow the link for instructions.

Do this command to update your GRUB menu:

sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

After booting into GRUB, select advanced options for ubuntu, then select the one you installed.

I hope this solved your problem as it did for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Try using a Livecd, and just let it run for a while, if the problem persists then you have a hardware problem.